# Flash TextField not tweening smoothly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

I'm having an issue with TextFields, whenever I tween the containers that they are inside of, the text will sorta jump and not scale very smoothly. Is there a solution to this problem? I have tried setting cacheAsBitmap, and that doesn't seem to have any effect. Thanks.

Wanted to add that I'm doing this in AIR, and the tweens are not linear, as in, not just an x tween, it is a tween that is affecting both x and y. I have a feeling it may be due to this.

Comment: Text fields or text field component?

Comment: TextField. I have not embedded them, but I included them in my swc. AIR app.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure they are anti-aliased for animation and not for readability. You can find the setting in the textfield properties. If using script, like TweenLite, you may also want to consider rounding the position on update.

Comment: you mean when the object is done tweening, then round the position? Not sure what you mean by rounding on update. thanks.

Comment: how do you antialias them for animation and not for readability? currently i am antialiasing them this way 'text.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;'

Comment: use `text.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.NORMAL;`, it's the same thing as "Anti-alias for Animation" in the Flash IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Change the anti-alias option to "antialias for animation" instead of "antialias for readablility."

Answer (score 2):

As people in other answers state, you can try to round the values the textfield is set to, to partly (sometimes totally) avoid such "jumps".

If you're using a tween engine, like TweenLite, eaze, anything like that, you can try to look for a method to round the position :

- for example by using the RoundPropsPlugin in Tweenlite,
- or using the Math.round(value) function in an onUpdate event coming from the tween itself.

Most of the time, good tweening engine will have either (or even both !) of these solutions possible (if not, maybe consider changing engine, [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) or [eaze](http://code.google.com/p/eaze-tween/) are the two bests in my opinion !)

Comment: hey i appreciate the answer, very informative... will try that. +1